# What is the meaning of (resp. closed) in set theory?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, definition

I'm sure this a spectacularly basic question but I can't seem to find the definition of this anywhere. 
 Here's some context:

> If $U$ and $V$ are open (resp. closed) then $U\cup V$ is open (resp.
>   $U\cap V$ is closed).  If $\left\{U_{i}\right\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is a
>   countable collection of open sets, must $\bigcap_{i\in I} U_{i}$ be
>   open? Provide a proof or counterexample.  Similarly, if
>   $\left\{A_{i}\right\}_{i\in I}$ is an infinite collection of closed
>   sets, must $\bigcap_{i\in I} A_{i}$ be closed?

Comment: The writer is trying to save time by giving two results at once.  The first says that the union of two open sets is open, the second says that the intersection of two closed sets is closed.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I understand it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, "resp." is an abbreviation for "respectively". So:

> If $U$ and $V$ are open (resp. closed) then $U\cup V$ is open (resp. $U\cap V$ is closed).

means:

> If $U$ and $V$ are open (respectively closed) then $U\cup V$ is open (respectively $U\cap V$ is closed).

which is a lazy way to write:

> If $U$ and $V$ are open then $U\cup V$ is open. If $U$ and $V$ are closed then $U\cap V$ is closed.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, I should have seen that, haha.

Comment: Typo, the last $\cup$ should be $\cap$.

Comment: @Ian Thanks, fixed